# read file into data frame with grouping variable

Tags: python, pandas

```
file.txt

///// A
13 32 12 13
4 22 34 42    
///// B
3 1 34 11
0 NaN 21 1
44 32 33 32  
///// C
5 32 11 21
43 23 NaN 3
```

I'm trying to read this file such that values are grouped according to the letter after `/////`. Desired output:

```
0   1   2   3   Group
13  32  12  13  A
4   22  34  42  A
3   1   34  11  B
0   NaN 21  1   B
44  32  33  32  B
5   32  11  21  C
43  23  NaN 3   C
```

I tried most options in `pd.read_table` but I don't know how to deal with the grouping, as I can only manage to read the file if I ignore the `/////` lines `df = pd.read_table('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None, comment='/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to read the group header and count the rows, then read your file treating the intermediate headers as comments and add the groups:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    groups = re.findall(r'/////\s*(\w+)|^', f.read(), flags=re.M)
s = pd.Series(groups)
m = s.eq('')

df = pd.read_table('file.txt', sep='\s+', header=None, comment='/')
df['group'] = s.mask(m).ffill()[m].values
```

output:

```
    0     1     2   3 group
0  13  32.0  12.0  13     A
1   4  22.0  34.0  42     A
2   3   1.0  34.0  11     B
3   0   NaN  21.0   1     B
4  44  32.0  33.0  32     B
5   5  32.0  11.0  21     C
6  43  23.0   NaN   3     C
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_list = []


def converter(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except:
        return np.nan


with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('/////'):
            group = line[-1]
        else:
            values = map(converter, line.split())
            df_list.append([*values, group])

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=[*[i for i in range(4)], 'Group'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am reading txt file with read_csv, and split the one column into two Alpha and num. lastly split the Num by space and create the new columns.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("t1.txt", header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)
df.insert(0, 'Group', df[0].where(df[0].str.startswith('/')).ffill())
df = df[df['Group'].ne(df[0])].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0:'NUM'})
df = df.join(df['NUM'].str.split(' ',3, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 3:'D'}))
```

Cleaning :

```
df['Group'] = df['Group'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1])
df.drop('NUM', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
 Group  A   B   C   D
0   A   13  32  12  13
1   A   4   22  34  42
2   B   3   1   34  11
3   B   0   NaN 21  1
4   B   44  32  33  32
5   C   5   32  11  21
6   C   43  23  NaN 3
```